# How solve django-admin is not recognized...?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying:

Django-admin startproject myweb

This is what i see:

'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable

---

Even i added python27/Scripts to my pc environment variables but didn't work

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/windows/ If you followed this tutorial you should've have it installed inside your venv if django-admin still not works try calling the django executable  with "py -m django-admin"

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the solution to your problem: You can do this using virtualenv. step by step

- `py -m pip install --user virtualenv`
- `py -m venv env`
- `.\env\Scripts\activate`
- `python -m pip install Django`

check version:

- `python -m django --version`

start project Command:

- `django-admin startproject mysite`

start app Command:

- `python manage.py startapp myapp`

now you can run project:

- `python manage.py runserver`

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to run `pip install django` first without activating virtual env, if you want to install django only in virtual env then you have to activate it first and then get django installed into that only after trigger the command `django-admin startproject myweb`